# The extended real line.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}' = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -∞ \} \cup \{∞\}$ be the extended or closed real line with the points $—∞$ and $∞$ added. The Borel sets $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb {R}')$ is the sigma-field generated by the sets $\{—∞,x]$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , where $[—∞,x] = \{—∞\} \cup (-∞, x]$. Show $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb {R}')$ is also generated by the following collections of sets:

(i) $[-∞,x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know the criteria for Borel sets, but I'm not sure how to formally prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how these can help you:

$(-\infty,x] = \cap_n (-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n})$ and

$(-\infty,x) = \cup_n (-\infty, x-\frac{1}{n}]$